# Can runs be scored by a boundary in the same legal ball as an Out - Hit wicket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Suppose a batsman plays the ball, gets out Hit wicket and the ball crosses the boundary. Will the runs be considered or not?

What changes if the batsman misses the ball, is out Hit wicket, and the ball carries to the boundary? Are four byes awarded in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Section 9 of [Law 18](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/) covers this situation - in both cases **no** runs are scored. Once the batsman is dismissed no runs can be credited to the batting side.

Answer (score -2):

Hit wicket is out so no runs will be considered and also bye is also not considered if the batsman is out.

Comment: Can you provide a resource(s) supporting your answer?